# if in case in while (bash number guessing game)

Tags: bash, shell

I am programming a little number-guessing game in bash.
This is the code so far:

```
   #!/bin/bash

#Number guessing

read -p "Who are you? " name

echo "Welcome, ${name}!"

read -p "How high do you want to guess? " level

number=$(($RANDOM % $level))

((attempts++))

while [[ ${guess} != ${number} ]]
do
read -p "Whats the number? " guess
case $guess in
$number) echo "Correct! You needed ${attempts} attempts"
break
;;
*) echo "Wrong..." 
((attempts++))
;;
esac
if [[ ${guess} > ${number} ]]
then
echo "Above."
else 
echo "Below."
fi
done
```

This asks for the users name, how high the numbers that have to be guessed go and then generates a random number based on $level. What I want to do is a echo whether the entered number was above or below the guessed number. The if at the end of the while-loop doesnt work and the same if in the last case *) echo "Wrong" doesnt work either. Is it possible to have such an if in a case in a while loop or do you have another solution?

Have a nice day

Comment: `${guess} != ${number}` string comparison. Use `-ne` instead.So is `${guess} > ${number}` use `-gt` instead.

Comment: Your `if` statement *isn't* in the `case` statement; it follows it.

Comment: @chepner irrelvant it still gets to the if in every loop.

Comment: Please, indent the code properly.

Comment: I know but as stated above I tried it with the if in the second case and it didnt work either @chepner

Answer (score 2):

`!=` and `>` are string comparison operators inside `[[ ... ]]`; you want integer comparison.

```
while [[ ${guess} -ne ${number} ]]

if [[ ${guess} -gt ${number} ]]
```

or better in `bash`, use an arithmetic statement where you *can* use the normal operators.

```
while (( guess != number ))

if (( guess > number ))
```

Comment: (( guess != number )) doesnt work thats why I put them in [[ ... ]]


but leaving them in [[...]] and using -gt in the if does work!